# Redirecting websocket traffic on port 80 with lighttpd

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, lighttpd

I have a website hosted on lighttpd, accessible at the "www" subdomain. I also have a chat server listening on port 8124 made with node.js and socket.io.

I want all client traffic to happen on port 80, by redirecting all requests to the "chat" subdomain to port 8124. So I enabled mod_proxy and in lighttpd.conf I added:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "chat.myserver.com" {
    proxy.server = (
            "" => ((
                    "host" => "78.128.79.192",
                    "port" => "8124"
            ))
    )
}
```

On the client, when I connect to the websocket,

```
var socket = io.connect('http://chat.myserver.com');
```

I get the right messages from node.js:

```
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 6067470561567883577
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/6067470561567883577
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 6067470561567883577
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
```

But the browser gives an error:

```
Firefox can't connect to server ws://chat.myserver.com/socket.io/1/websocket/6067470561567883577
```

Of course, everything works correctly if I connect directly to the port 8124:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://www.myserver.com:8124');
```

But, as I said, I would like all client traffic to be on port 80. Is it possibile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mod_proxy is known to be not compatible with websockets.

[HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) is compatible (I haven't tested it myself but here's an [article on its configuration for websockets](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/configuring-haproxy-for-websocket/)).

Comment: I've just installed Haproxy and it's working perfectly. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the confirmation as I hadn't tested it (as I said) and was looking forward to do it :)

Comment: Hi! I'm currently trying to make websocket with socket.io works with lighttpd and I'm facing an issue. It seems it can't connect to `ws://<mydomain.com>/socket.io/1/<randomNumbers>/ : 'Connection' header is missing`. What is your conf file of HAProxy as you said it works with it (instead of lighttp mod_proxy). Many thanks!

Comment: I installed HAProxy and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This solution is not really *websocket traffic on port 80 with lighttpd* but rather *websocket traffic on port 80* **without** *lighttpd*.In the linked article lighttpd (or any other webserver) listens on port 8080 and is not involved in serving ws connections in any way.