# Uploading file using websocket (tornado)

Tags: javascript, websocket, tornado

I'm using tornado's websocket in my project, and I would like to send a file (image) to the server using websocket and save it locally on the server. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely inefficient. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080112/large-file-upload-with-websocket).

Also, it's mostly client side solution - you need to send file by slices and write it on server by slices. You can do it, if you will think about slices as messages.