# How to pass a File object via postMessage or any similar function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to pass a `File` object via `postMessage` or any similar function?

I need to communicate between page-related JS code and the one from content script as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication).

If I try to pass it directly it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window':
>   An object could not be cloned

Answer (score 2):

The `Uncaught DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': An object could not be cloned` error message appears when postMessage sends an unsuported object as a parameter.

Check this [page](https://mattandre.ws/2014/05/javascript-wormholes-playing-channel-messaging/) on how to play with channel message.

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055730/transfer-file-to-webworker-datacloneerror-the-object-could-not-be-cloned), alternative way is to use an array of the backing ArrayBuffer instances of any typed arrays you wish to pass.