# Rails - getting a correct class from jQuery for Paperclip

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, actioncable

I'm trying to get the PaperClip params by using jQuery and create an image directly.

i did something like

```
imageData = new FormData();
imageData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

and I passed the `imageData` to a ruby function like

```
  send_message: function(imageData) {
    return this.perform('send_message', {
      image: imageData
    });
```

but when I tried to create a message like

```
Messages.create!(image: data['image'])
```

it returns an error

```
Could not execute command from ({"command"=>"message", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"ConversationsChannel\", "data"=>"{\"image\":{},\"action\":\"send_message\"}"})
[Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError - No handler found for {}]
```

No idea why `imageData == {}` while `$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0])` returns something like

```
File {name: "image.png", lastModified: 1499752728000, lastModifiedDate: Tue Jul 11 2017 13:58:48 GMT+0800 (HKT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 602802…}
```

I know that PaperClip requires something like this in `params`, but not sure how to get this from jQuery

```
"asset"=>
  {"image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000056679e8
    @content_type="image/jpg",
    @headers= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[image]\";
      filename=\"2009-11-29-133527.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg\r\n",
    @original_filename=""2009-11-29-133527.jpg"",
    @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120619-1043-yvc9ox>>}
```

Comment: At the very least, you can encode them in Base64 (or something), decode on the client and show.

Comment: [Here is a very clear and good answer. In short, you can, but ActionCable dont have an interface for that. Use plain POST request.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11081396/2057388)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use active storage https://github.com/rails/activestorage to upload image and you can display it through action cable.