# cross-browser solution for downloading large files from authenticated endpoint

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, blob, filesaver.js

I'm searching for a way for downloading big files (like 2 - 4 Gb) on a bearer token protected api endpoint, that works on all common browsers (IE 11, Chrome, Firefox, Android Browsers, Safari). It should work with angular/ts and browsers  only (without providing an app).

**The problem with FileSaver**

At the moment I'm using [eligrey/filesaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which kinda combines all browser specific possibilities for a client side blob download. With this approach i can easely use the bearer token (ex. with http interceptors).

The problem is, *IE pumps up the RAM and gets stuck at 1.4 GB download.*

**The problem with StreamSaver**

I saw there is a new modern way with [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js), which allows streaming directly on disk, *but it is only available on chrome and opera.*

**The Problem with an unprotected endpoint**

Another common way for such a scenario would be to allow anonymous access for the download endpoint, with requesting a one-time-token first, creating a url containing this token, let the user download it directly via browser with opening a new tab and immediately close it after starting the download.

*This approach takes 2 requests for a download and looks flashy for a user to watch. I'm not sure, if this works on mobile browsers (opening new tab for download) and it looks like a hack, at least to me. The API have to ensure that url's are only valid during a short period of time and/or cannot be used 2 times in a row.*

**Ideas, anyone?**

Does anyone knows a clean, modern/state of the art & performant way for such a common scenario?

How are the big companys dealing with this problem (google drive, dropbox, amazaon)?

I personally would prefer to let the browser download the file (instead of client side blob download). Maybe there is a way to "inject" the bearer tokens as default request headers to the browser when the client clicks a (href'ed) link.

*Why isn't it easy for an modern angular rich-client to delegate a protected binary download to the browser?*

Comment: One approach I've seen in the past is to generate a short-lived unauthenticated URL to download the file. S3 access links that expire automatically are one way to achieve this, assuming your files are on S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any method to solve your issue regarding `FileSaver.js` and `StreamSaver.js`.

Nonetheless I had a similiar problem to solve, which points at your thoughts of using an "unprotected endpoint".

Well, I would go and create a one-time token to the file, which is included in URL of course. 
(I know, I know, it's not the best solution - I'd appreciate if someone comes up with a "best" practice for this)

Your thoughts mentioned a "flashy" and nasty behaviour for the user.
I found a solution to solve this "flashy" problem by injecting a form which triggers the download.

```
jQuery('<form action="' + YOUR_URL + '" method="get"></form>')
    .appendTo('body')
    .submit()
    .remove();
```

The download is then handled by the standard download dialog of your browser, without that nasty a new tab opens and closes immediately.

Note:

> I haven't tested this for files of your size. But it works for files until 1GB flawlessly. Maybe you give it a shot and I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for sharing your experience with this! Can you say anything about this approach on mobile devices (android browser, iOS safari?). I'll definitly try that - if i really have to go that way (well.. it looks like, there is no other option ;o)). At least there is no "flashy" effect that way.

Comment: It's working on Chrome for Android and Stock Android Browsers like Samsungs (don't know how they call it). I even created an app which consists of a webview for Android - works, no problems there. Also it's working iOS running Safari. But still, if you should encounter a problem there, let me know.

Comment: cool, thanks - if no one brings up a better solution in 5 hours, i'll accept yours

Answer (score 1):

Why not websocket ? 
Expecting that it is probably not the best method (according to the best answer of this [near similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080112/large-file-upload-with-websocket)), but I copy-paste the @Ibrahim Muhammad's answer in case it may help you:

> You could use https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs or
>   https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js if you can run node.js on the
>   server.

Comment: Thank you, i'll take a look at it. But as i know websockets are not doing great with internet explorer..? Unfortunately I can't run nodejs there.