# Can't access to socket.io.js on Raspberry Pi with Lighttpd [Node.JS & Socket.IO]

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, socket.io, lighty

I'm completely new to Node.JS and Socket.IO since yesterday.

I try to make Node.JS and Socket.IO work on my Raspberry Pi but it doesn't seem to. **I can't access to `<myip>:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js`.**
I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.bartbania.com/index.php/deploying-node-js-with-lighttpd/) so my Lighttpd.conf file seems like so:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "<myURLtomywebsite>" {
    proxy.server = (" " => ((
        "host" => "<myIP>",
        "port" => 1337)
    )
)
```

My `server.js` look like so:

```
var http = require('http');

httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.end('Hello World!');
});

httpServer.listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
var clients = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    ++clients;

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
        --clients;
        io.sockets.emit('disusr', clients);
    });

    io.sockets.emit('newusr', clients);
});
```

And I bind to the `disusr` and `newusr` events in my `client.js` to display the number of connected users in a `div`.

Everything looks fine on my `localhost` but, in production environment, I cannot link to my `socket.io.js` file on the `1337` port. To be honest, I'm not even sure what address to use? (URL of my website appended with `:1337`, `localhost`, some other address I would have created?)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I use nodejs and socket io in one personal and easy project at home. I use no lighttpd for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem!

I linked `socket.io.js` like so : `<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

I used HAProxy instead of Lighttpd mod_proxy as specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947298/redirecting-websocket-traffic-on-port-80-with-lighttpd?rq=1)

Here is my conf file (amend `<...>` per your configuration):

```
# this config needs haproxy-1.1.28 or haproxy-1.2.1

global
  log  127.0.0.1  local0
  log  127.0.0.1  local1 notice
  maxconn  4096
  uid  99
  gid  99
  daemon

defaults
  log   global
  mode  http
  option  httplog
  option  dontlognull
  retries  3
  option http-use-proxy-header
  option  redispatch
  option  http-server-close
  maxconn  2000
  contimeout  5000
  clitimeout  50000
  srvtimeout  50000

frontend public
  bind *:80
  acl is_example hdr_end(host) -i <URL.toyourwebsite.com>
  acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
  acl is_websocket path_beg -i /websockets
  use_backend ws if is_websocket is_example
  default_backend www

backend ws
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor # This sets X-Forwarded-For
    timeout queue 5000
    timeout server 86400000
    timeout connect 86400000
    server apiserver localhost:<PORT> weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

And I made Lighttpd listened to the 8080 port (otherwise HAProxy wouldn't start).

Remind there is no need to use mod_proxy as it is known to be not compatible with websockets. Use HAProxy instead.

Comment: At the time of this post, lighttpd mod_proxy did not support websockets, but since lighttpd 1.4.46 (released Oct 2017), [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_proxy) does support websockets, if lighttpd.conf is configured to do so.