# Error when using ssl with websocket

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, https, websocket

I am using ssl communication with websocket.
so I added the secure communication in my javascript code like this  `"wss://myip"`
when lunch a websocket communication from my page with `https://myip`
i get the following error.

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I am using  lighttpd server and chrome navigator on a linux machine.

could any one help me?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At present, this does not appear to be supported by lighttpd.  The following link suggests using HAProxy as frontend to proxy the traffic to the websockets application:

[Redirecting websocket traffic on port 80 with lighttpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947298/redirecting-websocket-traffic-on-port-80-with-lighttpd)

(actually *without* lighttpd)